# Organizing library files

Tags: c++

I am kind of new to C++ (finished my first book a couple weeks ago) and I am just starting to use libraries (like OpenGL), but I am not really good at organizing files, so my directory structure is quickly looking very messy.

I have a C++ directory where I want to keep all my files related to C++. I use Visual Studio 2019 and whenever I start a new project, I put it directly into the C++ directory.

Should I put all the include and lib files into an include and lib directory that would be inside each project and copy and paste them into a new project each time I want to use that specific library again? Should I put an include and a lib directory into my C++ directory that I put all the header files and lib files that I have ever used into? Or is there something else you would recommend?

Comment: ***Should I put an include and a lib directory into my C++ directory that I put all the header files and lib files that I have ever used into?*** If you are talking about putting files in the same folders as your compiler uses for the system my answer is: No don't do that. If you have created your own lib folder and include folder that is an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on how independent you want your projects to be.

In general making each project depend on a set of shared files seems like a good idea. However, in practice, specially if you are just starting out, it is better to keep separate copies.

The reason is that when you are learning, you will be improving your common files all the time, iterating on them and even redesigning them. This means every time you do this you will have to go back to all your projects and check if they still compile and work. That may be useful or not depending on what you are doing. If the files had been duplicated, your old projects would continue working without need for maintenance.

That is why I'd recommend waiting until you are more experienced. This does not apply in other situations, of course. If you are making an actual production library or you are making a tutorial series for others to learn, you really want to be providing a single library.